# Probability that duplicates are still in the deck after X card drawn

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, card-games

Deck has 30 cards, out of which 5 cards have duplicates (20 cards are unique, 5 cards have 2 copies each).

If you draw X cards from the deck (without returning), what is the probability that there are at least one duplicate remaining in the deck?

Comment: Also, by "there **are** at least one duplicate remaining in the deck", do you mean that at least $2$ copies of a card are remaining?

Comment: I have a B.Sc. degree in math, however, I finished my University back in 2001 so my memory is not fresh since I haven't worked with probability. But I can read math text, just started to read about hypergeometric distribution

Comment: To answer your second question "there are at least one duplicate remaining in the deck" means that there are 2 copies of the same card in the deck. This question is actually related to the game Hearthstone

Comment: Recursive methods at least give an answer:  if $P(x,T,d)$ is the probability that a duplicate remains given $x$ draws from $T$ cards of which $2d$ have a duplicate, then $P(x,T,d)=\frac {2d}TP(x-1,T-1,d-1)+\frac {T-2d}T P(x-1,T-1,d)$ and $x<d\implies P(x,T,d)=1$, $P(x,T,0)=0$.  I expect there is a closed formula, though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct. 

Assume that X is less than 28 (so there are at least 3 cards in the deck remaining), than possible combinations for remaining cards are $30 \choose 30-X$ 

Possibility to select $30-X$ cards with selected duplicate is $ {28 \choose 28-X}  * 5$ . 

So it seems $$1 - \frac{{28 \choose 28-X} * 5}{{30 \choose 30 - X}}$$

Comment: @MladenAdamovic  Isn't this negative quite often?  if say...$X=10$ this gives $-1.655$.

Comment: Yeah, this seems incorrect. I did use Matlab function `1 - (nchoosek(28, 30-X-2) * 5 / nchoosek(30, 30-X))` on http://www.online-utility.org to figure out that this brings negative numbers....

Comment: Also worth noting that it is not difficult to computed the expected number of duplicates that remains.  Using indicator variables for each duplicate we get $E=5\times \left(\frac {29-(x-1)}{30}\right)\times \left(\frac {28-(x-1)}{29}\right)$

Comment: @lulu that P formula seems not being correct, for T=30, d = 15, X=15 the result is 0.0026679. That is too low probability if each card has a dupe that after 15 draws there are no dupes

Comment: @lulu also that E formula seems being incorrect, I did use a program `(d * choose(d - 1 - (x - 1), (int) T) * choose(d - 2 - x + 1, 29)) / choose(30, 30 - x)` and for 0 draws it is negative for x=1 is 0 and for x=2 I've got division by zero

Comment: Don't have time to go over it now, but I will later.  The expectation calculation should be easy (though I could well have botched the algebra).  Just compute the probability that the first card is not chosen then (contingent on the first card not being drawn) compute the probability that the second is also not drawn.  Then take the product.  That's all I intended...though as I say, I could certainly have made an algebraic blunder.

Comment: Quick point:  my formula for $E$ involves no binomial coefficients.  Those are just fractions.  If I take $x=1$ this yields $4.\overline 6$ which is correct (you have $5$ duplicates with probability $\frac 23$ and $4$ duplicates with probability $\frac 13$).

Comment: @lulu even if that E formula is correct (I honestly don't understand it) still I need a probability not expected number of dupes to remain and I don't know how to calculate from that probability

Comment: I didn't say the expectation was a complete answer, I just said it was worth noting.  I expect the recursion is correct...I don't see a problem with it.YOur calculation is clearly wrong, however...the first stage of the recursion gives $P(15,30,15)=P(14,29,14)$ and the second stage gives $\frac {28}{29}P(13,29,13) + \frac 1{29}$ and $\frac 1{29}$ is already greater than the value you suggest.

Comment: @lulu I think this could be a recursive formula. If $P(x, T, d)$  is the probability that a duplicate remains given $x$ draws from $T$ cards of which $2d$ have a duplicate than: if $d = 0$ then $P = 0$. If $x < 2d$ then $P=1$. Otherwise $P(x, T, d) = \frac{2d}{T-x} P(x-1, T, d-1) + \frac{x-2d}{T-x} P(x-1, T, d)$ . Let me know write a code to check it out.

Comment: The formula i wrote is a recursion.  I don't understand your version of it.

Comment: I figured out my formula is incorrect. What do you mean by "given $x$ draws", is it after $x$ draws? If so, your rule $x < d$ seems obviously wrong. But the idea could work, I did wrote some on paper, now going to check for errors.

Comment: Uops, sorry, $x < d$ , $P = 1$ indeed.

Comment: @lulu your recurrent formula seems correct actually, I've manually checked it with $P(5, 7, 2)$ and it seems it brings correct results. Congrats!

Comment: uops, that recurrent function seems not being  correct, I went today to double check it and I got a different result than brute force solution

Comment: for $P(7, 10, 2)$ correct result seems to be 0.13333333333333333 (brute force calculated)

Answer (score 1):

Say there are $n$ cards, including $k$ pairs and $n-2k$ singletons, and we draw $m$ cards. The probability that a pair remains can be determined by inclusion-exclusion. There are $\binom kj$ ways to choose $j$ particular pairs, and the probability that they remain in the deck is $\frac{\binom{n-2j}m}{\binom nm}$. Thus the probability that no pair remains is

$$
\binom nm^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj\binom{n-2j}m\;,
$$

and the probability that at least one pair remains is the complement,

$$
\binom nm^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j-1}\binom kj\binom{n-2j}m\;.
$$

In your case, with $n=30$, $k=5$ and $m=X$, this is

$$
\binom{30}X^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^5(-1)^{j-1}\binom5j\binom{30-2j}X\\
=\binom{30}X^{-1}\left(5\binom{28}X-10\binom{26}X+10\binom{24}X-5\binom{22}X+\binom{20}X\right)\;.
$$

[Here's a table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=table%20of%20%285%20*%20binom%20%2828,X%29%20-%2010%20*%20binom%20%2826,X%29%20%2B%2010%20*%20binom%20%2824,X%29%20-%205%20*%20binom%20%2822,X%29%20%2B%20binom%20%2820,X%29%29%20%2F%20binom%2830,X%29%20for%20X%3D0..30) of the values for $0\le X\le30$.